# Retrieving RGB vector from pixel in Julia

Tags: floating-point, julia, rgb, pixel

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to retrieve the components of the RGB vector of a pixel in Julia. For example, if I have an image I call `image` and I pick a pixel, say `image[230, 1566]`, then if I wanted, say, the green component of the RGB vector, my inclination is to just do `RGB(image[230, 1566]).g`. However, such a thing would return a string like `0.778N0f8`. I know that means "Normalized with 8 fractional bits," but this is not what I want. I simply want the actual float as a number so I can perform other operations on it. Any idea how I can get around this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `0.778N0f8` isn't a string, it is an actual number that you can operate on. Try `0.778N0f8 + 1` for example. If there are any operations you get into trouble with, you can do `float(0.778N0f8)` or use any conversion, like `Float16` or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

To have a better understanding what is going on let us consider a pixel:

```
julia> using Colors

julia> pixel = colorant"purple"
RGB{N0f8}(0.502,0.0,0.502)
```

We can see that the `RGB` type by default uses the type `N0f8` to store it values. Let us look inside.

```
julia> dump(pixel)
RGB{FixedPointNumbers.N0f8}
  r: FixedPointNumbers.N0f8
    i: UInt8 0x80
  g: FixedPointNumbers.N0f8
    i: UInt8 0x00
  b: FixedPointNumbers.N0f8
    i: UInt8 0x80
```

You can see that internally, in fact, a pixel holds a set of 3 unsigned 8 bit integer numbers named `r`, `g`, `b` that hold their value in the `i` field.

The correct way to access those values is however through `red`, `green`, `blue` methods rather than fields:

```
julia> dump(red(pixel))
FixedPointNumbers.N0f8
  i: UInt8 0x80
```

If you want to get as the floating point value you can do  `float(red(pixel)))`:

```
julia> dump(float(red(pixel)))
Float32 0.5019608f0
```

Note however that now the returned value is 4x larger than the original data (32 bits instead of 8).

If you rather want to get the raw data (which is 8 bits) you can do:

```
julia> reinterpret(red(pixel))
0x80
```

Hope that clears it all.

Comment: Thanks for that very thorough response. It's much appreciated!

Comment: This is an outstanding answer. To amplify on why "the correct way to access those values is through `red`, ...": Julia's color ecosystem also supports common color encoding schemes like `ARGB32` which pack a color into particular bits of a `UInt32`. In that case there is no `c.r` field to access, but `red(c)` will nevertheless return the value of the red channel. The accessor methods are always safe no matter what the representation.